# Emitting Tuple to different Bolts

Tags: apache-storm

I am trying of a scenario in which I have a Spout which reads a data from a Message Broker and emits the message as a tuple  to a Bolt for some Processing.

Bolt post processing converts it into seperate Messages and each sub- message has to be sent  to different Brokers which can be hosted on different machines .

Assuming I have finite recipients (in my case there are 3 Message Brokers for output) .

So , Bolt1 post processing can either drop the message directly to these 3 Message Brokers

Now, If I use a single Bolt here which drops the messages to these three brokers by itself and lets say One of them fails(due to unavailability etc)  on which I call the collector's  fail method  .

Once the fail method is called on the bolt , in my Spout fail method gets Invoked .

Here , I believe I will have to again process the entire message again (I have to make sure everyMessage has to be processed ) even though 2 out of 3 messages got successfully delivered .

Alternatively , even If I emit these 3 sub messages to different bolt , I think even in that case Spout will have to process the entire message again .

This is because I am appending a Unique Guid with the message while emitting it first time in the spout nextTuple() method .

Is there a way to ensure that only the failed sub message should be processed and not entire one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Storm (low level Java API) provides only "at-least-once" processing guarantees, ie, there is no support to avoid duplicate processing on case of failure.

If you need exactly once proceeding, you can use Trident on top of Storm. However, even Trident can not give exactly once if you emit data to an external system (if the external system cannot detect and delete duplicates). This is not a Storm specific but general problem. Other system like Apache Flink, Apache Spark Streaming, or S-Store (a recent research prototype system from MIT -> Stonebraker) "suffer" from the exact same problem.

Maybe the best approach would be to try out Trident to evaluate if it can meet your requirements.